# targetSdkVersion restriction for retained versions

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We have an app on Google Play which makes use of Google Play's multi-apk feature. The first apk is the old one that targets the pre-Lollipop devices and retained for those of our users who did not update their smartphones yet. Its targetSdkVersion set to 19, if I remember correctly. We do not intend to provide any updates for that version, as all development happens only for the new version.

The second apk targets everything post-Lollipop and its targetSdkVersion is set to 26.

We've got an email from Google some days ago which asks us to bump the targetSdkVersion to 26 asap. If I am correct, that email is about the retained version (which we do not want to update anyway).

Now, I've read all documentation and articles I could find, but I did not find any info here on the our scenario. What will be the behaviour of the Google Play in case we make an update of the newer app after November 2018? Will they restrict the update unless we update the old apk as well or we are safe and we can just keep the retained version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Play Console Help section [Target API level requirements for the Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk) states it the most directly:

> Once these requirements come into effect, the Play Console will prevent you from submitting new APKs using older target API levels.

The target API level requirement only affects the new APKs that you upload. Any existing APK targeting an older API level can remain published, and does not affect your ability to upload new APKs.

It is fine for you to leave your pre-Lollipop APK published on an older targetSdkVersion. Your new APK versions must target API level 26 or higher.

Comment: Hey, Edward! Really nice to see your answer here, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

[Google's blogpost from late last year](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html) appears to address your question (emphasis mine):

> In order to provide users with the best Android experience possible, the Google Play Console will require that apps target a recent API level:
>
> - August 2018: New apps required to target API level 26 (Android 8.0) or higher.
> - November 2018: **Updates to** existing apps required to target API level 26 or higher.
> - 2019 onwards: Each year the targetSdkVersion requirement will advance. Within one year following each Android dessert release, new apps and app updates will need to target the corresponding API level or higher.
>
> **Existing apps that are not receiving updates are unaffected.**

Comment: Hey, Michael, thanks for the answer. 

Yes, I also read that article. The part that seems a bit vague to me is what they understand by "app". Is is the app as "app on Google Play" or the app as "one of the apks served to the users from within the single app on Google Play"? Because we have single app page on Google play, with 2 different apks attached to it. And the question is - do we need to ensure we target the most recent targetSdkVersion in _all_ apks attached to that app page, or just the one that we want to be able to update?

Comment: My understanding is that you'll only need to increase the `targetSdkVersion` for something that you want to publish an update to. So if you upload the two APKs independently - even though they're the "same" app - I don't see your legacy APK being affected. But I agree that they're not explicitly covering that particular scenario. There's a chat service when you're logged into the Google Play developer console, where you can ask questions to the Google Play support team. You could try asking them for clarification on this matter.

Comment: Ok, I asked the question via support mail, let's see what their answer will be and I'll repost it here. Thanks again for the help @Michael!